# Angular 2 popup window

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, popupwindow

I am trying to create a popup window which asks for login details on button click.

my app.component looks like

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: `mytemplate.html`
 })
export class AppComponent {}
```

in index.html i referred to jquery and bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

mytemplate.html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">start here</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form id="login-form">
<div class="modal-body">

<input id="username"  type="text" placeholder="Username" >
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
</div>

</div>
</form>
</div>

</div>

</div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly for me . but i want to know is it possible to do the same purely Using angular2-modal ? if so can someone guide me how to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used angular2/modal and its good. You have to create a custom modal window to achieve the output of upper code. Place your Login code in a separate component (login.component.ts) and then use this component as a custom modal.

Follow this plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/mbPzd8/ . Be sure to use angular2-modal@2.0.0-beta and add the angular2-modal module in your AppModule after installing.

Create a Login component with the following ts and template:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { DialogRef, ModalComponent, CloseGuard } from 'angular2-modal';
    import { BSModalContext } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';

    @Component({
      selector: 'login',
      styles: [],
      template: `<div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Login</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                 <form id="login-form">
                 <div class="modal-body">

                 <input placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="model.username" name="username" #username="ngModel" required>
                </input>
                  <input placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" name="password" #password="ngModel" required>
                </input>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Login</button>
                </div>`
    })
    export class LoginModal implements CloseGuard, ModalComponent<CustomModalContext> {
      context: CustomModalContext;

      public username: string;
      public password: string;

      constructor(public dialog: DialogRef<CustomModalContext>) {
        this.context = dialog.context; // this is the dialog reference
        dialog.setCloseGuard(this);
      }
    }
```

And now in app component, lets call this modal window.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginModal } from './login.component.ts';
import { Overlay, overlayConfigFactory } from 'angular2-modal';
import { Modal, BSModalContext } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<button (click)="openLoginDialog()">Login Modal</button>`
 })
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public modal: Modal) {
  }

  openLoginDialog() {
    return this.modal.open(LoginModal,  overlayConfigFactory({}, BSModalContext));
  }
}
```

Comment: i checked your while surfing itself and i tried to implement it. but i couldn't get it work . But that was seriously a good one but since i am new to angular2 i couldn't able to get it into my head

Comment: I am facing some issues in loading angular2-modal popup.After compiling when I try to launch the application, it is trying to evaluate the file in the path "Evaluating http://localhost:49928/lib/angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap.js"
But in the specified location lib/angular2-modal/plugins/ no such file exists and hence the application is getting crashed.
Any ideas why I am getting this error? Why it is looking for bootstrap.js file under angular2-modal?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600236/unexpected-token-evaluating-lib-angular2-modal-plugins-bootstrap-js-missi

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is but it might be easiest to use a third party component such as PrimeNg...
http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog

It provides an easy to use popup component.

If you can't use a 3rd party component you could just use css styles to make a div act like the popup. When a button is clicked on the page you would make the div visible using *ngIf. The div would contain a button to also close the div if its visible.

You could use the css styles that are mentioned in this blog...
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: thanks for the quick response . but i have to implement it only  using Angular 2 modal

Comment: I have added to the above answer.

Comment: @BenCameron thats a bad approach to do it. Using any package like angular2-modal or ngPrime dialog is better i think. Also its necessary to avoid any *ngIf statements on dialog divs and handle the opening and closing of dialog properly using either functions provided by the package them self or by user's input