# Unexpected token < - Evaluating /lib/angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap.js - missing file bootstrap.js in lib folder

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I am facing some issues in loading angular2-modal popup. Getting this exception "Unexpected token < - missing file lib/angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap.js"
After compiling when I try to launch the application, it is trying to evaluate the file in the path

"`Evaluating http://localhost:49928/lib/angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap.js`"

But in the specified location no such file exists and hence the application is getting crashed. Under the lib/angular2-modal/plugins/ folder, bootstrap.js file doesn't exists. But why is it looking for this file here?

```
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:49928/app/AppModule.js:13:19)
        at eval (http://localhost:49928/app/AppModule.js:110:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:49928/app/AppModule.js:111:3)
    Evaluating http://localhost:49928/lib/angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:49928/app/AppModule.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:49928/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:49928/app/main.js
```

SystemJS.Config.js file is as below

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            //'npm:': 'node_modules/'
            'npm:': 'lib/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',

            'angular2-modal': 'npm:angular2-modal'
         },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-modal': {
                main: 'bundles/angular2-modal.umd',
                defaultExtension: 'js',
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

My package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~4.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~4.1.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.6",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4",
    "angular2-modal": "2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",

    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-conventional-changelog": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-git": "^1.12.0",
    "gulp-header": "^1.8.8",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.5.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

AppModule.ts

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler }         from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }      from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }       from '@angular/http';
import { NgbModule }        from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { ModalModule } from 'angular2-modal';
import { BootstrapModalModule } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';
import { Overlay, overlayConfigFactory } from 'angular2-modal';
import { Modal } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';
import { DialogRef, ModalComponent, CloseGuard } from 'angular2-modal';
import { BSModalContext } from 'angular2-modal/plugins/bootstrap';
...

@NgModule({
    imports:
    [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ModalModule.forRoot(),
        BootstrapModalModule,
        LOGIN_ROUTER_PROVIDERS
    ],
    declarations:
    [
        AppLoader,
        Login,
        Home,
        ..
    ],
    providers:
    [
        ....
        {
            provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: CustomErrorHandler
        }
    ],
    entryComponents:
    [
        ....
        StoryBook, AddStoryBook
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppLoader]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Any ideas why I am getting this error? Why it is looking for plugins/bootstrap.js file under angular2-modal folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.

I have changed my systemjs.config.js file as per below and now it works.

```
 (function (global) {
var ngVer = '@4.1.1'; // lock in the angular package version; do not let it float to current!
    var routerVer = '@4.1.1'; // lock router version
    var formsVer = '@4.1.1'; // lock forms version


    var angular2ModalVer = '@2.0.2';
    var plugin = 'bootstrap'; // js-native / vex

    global.angular2ModalVer = angular2ModalVer;


    //map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'app',

        '@angular': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular', // sufficient if we didn't pin the version
        '@angular/router': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/router' + routerVer,
        '@angular/forms': 'https://unpkg.com/@angular/forms' + formsVer,

        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'https://unpkg.com/angular2-in-memory-web-api', // get latest
        'rxjs': 'https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.0.1',
        'ts': 'https://unpkg.com/plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/plugin.js',
        'typescript': 'https://unpkg.com/typescript@1.9.0-dev.20160409/lib/typescript.js',


        'angular2-modal': 'https://unpkg.com/angular2-modal' + angular2ModalVer
    };

    //packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        app: {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
            main: './index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'angular2-modal': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'bundles/angular2-modal.umd' }
        //'angular2-modal': {
        //    main: 'bundles/angular2-modal.umd',
        //    defaultExtension: 'js',
        //},
        //'angular2-modal/bundles/bootstrap': {
        //    main: 'angular2-modal.bootstrap.umd',
        //    defaultExtension: 'js'
        //}
    };
    //var packages = {
    //    'app': { main: './main.js', defaultExtension: 'ts' },
    //    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    //    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    //    'angular2-modal': { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'bundles/angular2-modal.umd' }
    //};

    // UMD bundles
    map[`angular2-modal/plugins/${plugin}`] = map['angular2-modal'] + '/bundles';
    packages[`angular2-modal/plugins/${plugin}`] = { defaultExtension: 'js', main: `angular2-modal.${plugin}.umd` };

    // Uncomment to use Individual files/modules
    // map[`angular2-modal/plugins/${plugin}`] = map['angular2-modal'] + `/plugins/${plugin}`;
    // packages['angular2-modal'] = { defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'index' };
    // packages[`angular2-modal/plugins/${plugin}`] =  { defaultExtension: 'js', main: `index` };  




    var ngPackageNames = [
      'common',
      'compiler',
      'core',
      'http',
      'platform-browser',
      'platform-browser-dynamic',
      'upgrade',
    ];

    // Add map entries for each angular package
    // only because we're pinning the version with `ngVer`.
    ngPackageNames.forEach(function (pkgName) {
        map['@angular/' + pkgName] = 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/' + pkgName + ngVer;
    });

    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.concat(['forms', 'router', 'router-deprecated']).forEach(function (pkgName) {

        // Bundled (~40 requests):
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };

        // Individual files (~300 requests):
        //packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    });

    var config = {
        // DEMO ONLY! REAL CODE SHOULD NOT TRANSPILE IN THE BROWSER
        transpiler: 'ts',
        typescriptOptions: {
            tsconfig: true
        },
        meta: {
            'typescript': {
                "exports": "ts"
            }
        },
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };

    System.config(config);

})(this);
```